# Prove that $a<b$ iff $a^3<b^3$ (don't use difference of two cubes)

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I would like to know a different proof for this problem:
Let $a,b\in \Bbb  R$. Show that  $a<b$ iff $a^3 < b^3$.
Given that it is not much difficult to prove by using a difference of cubes and that becomes an issue as you try to prove the same statement but with a greater exponent (odd).

I hope there aren't any mistakes in the way I wrote the statement.

Answer (score 5):

If $a=0$, or $a<0\le b$, we're done. (That wouldn't be the case for even powers, of course.) Now for the case providing the crux of the proof: if $a>0$ then $a^3<a^2b<ab^2<b^3$ (for higher odd powers, you'd just have a longer chain like this). If $a<b<0$, $|b|^3<|a|^3$ so the previous case completes the proof.

Comment: Or you can argue for the all negative case $a^2gt 0, ab\gt 0, b^2\gt 0$ so you can multiply the original inequality by these positive numbers to get the chain, rather than using the modulus. (Or just use $-b$ rather than $|b|$)

Comment: Thank you so much, when I posted this question I didn't know how to make a comment, but I read it as soon as you posted your answer. It was very useful and I found a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: @2shy2ask you can post your solution, too.

Comment: @2shy2ask [Please consider](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) kelalaka's suggestion, once you have at least 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Take set A=X such that x³0 lies in the set so (b+h)³b³+h³+3b²h>b³+h³
Which is greater than b³ so this is a contradiction so for "a" to lie in this set, a cannot be greater b...also "a" cannot be equal to b since it is a strict inequality...so a

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Please consult this [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide. I suspect even with such formatting your argument may need further clarification.

Comment: @J.G. hey can u help me.... I proved it using real analysis but I can't write it down here ;-;

Comment: I just don't understand your argument. Are you saying $a<b\implies\exists h>0(b=a+h)$? (Because if so, your write-up seems to have exchanged the roles of the labels $a,\,b$ relative to the OP.)

Comment: @J.G. can u see my entire proof ?? I can't see it myself after posting

Comment: Yes I am proving it by contradiction.....that a cannot be greater than b ..a cannot be equal to B so has to be less than b